# Function for identification of all the columns have DATE data and change its format in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains more than one column with DATE type. I want to identify all the columns that have DATE data and change their format to dd-mmm-yyyy.

```
dataset <- data.frame(Customer_Name, Country, Transaction, Delivery, Return, Cost)
```

### Lets assume transaction, delivery and return have date data.

Change the date data format of all date columns to dd-mmm-yyyy

## Expected Outputed :

Date Column(s) : Transaction, Delivery, Return

## And the dataset has now all the date data in dd-mmm-yyyy format.

I want to create a function for this `fun <- function(dataset) {}`

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. To help us help you please put your code and data in the question. You may find it helpful to write an excellent question by following the guidance in this link [MRE]. Please, please add some data in a dataframe format e.g. df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "b", "c")) obviously with your own data! And either explain what your have tried out prior to asking your question, ideally with the code you have tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Illustrative data:

```
dataset <- data.frame(Customer_Name = c("A", "B"), 
                      Country = c("X", "Y"), 
                      Transaction = c("01-01-2009", "31-01-2012"), 
                      Delivery = c("01-02-2009", "01-02-2012"), 
                      Return = c("27-02-2009", "22-03-2012"), 
                      Cost = c(1234, 5678))

dataset
  Customer_Name Country Transaction   Delivery     Return Cost
1             A       X  01-01-2009 01-02-2009 27-02-2009 1234
2             B       Y  31-01-2012 01-02-2012 22-03-2012 5678
```

To change the date format for all date columns in one go, first identify all columns containing date values with `grepl`and regex and then use `format`and `as.Date` inside `lapply`:

```
dataset[apply(dataset, 2, function(x) all(grepl("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}", x)))] <- 
  lapply(dataset[apply(dataset, 2, function(x) all(grepl("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}", x)))], 
         function(x) format(as.Date(x, format = "%d-%m-%Y"), "%d-%b-%Y"))
```

Result:

```
dataset
  Customer_Name Country Transaction    Delivery      Return Cost
1             A       X 01-Jan-2009 01-Feb-2009 27-Feb-2009 1234
2             B       Y 31-Jan-2012 01-Feb-2012 22-Mär-2012 5678
```

**EDIT**:

If the dates are in different formats, this solution will help:

Data:

```
dataset <- data.frame(Customer_Name = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                      Country = c("X", "Y", "Z"), 
                      Transaction = c("01-Mar-2015", "31-01-2012", "15/01/1999"), 
                      Delivery = c("01-02-2018", "01/08/2016", "17-09-2007"), 
                      Return = c("27/11/2009", "22-Jan-2013", "20-Nov-1987"), 
                      Cost = c(1234, 5678, 6655))
```

To avoid overcrowding the `apply`statement below let's define two shorthand vectors, one for the patterns through which columns with dates will be detected and one for the different date formats:

```
date_patterns <- "\\d{2}(-|/)\\d{2}(-|/)\\d{4}|\\d{2}-\\w+-\\d{2}"
date_formats <- c("%d-%m-%Y", "%d/%m/%Y", "%d-%b-%Y")
```

The transformation of the differnt dates to one standardized date format, namely `%d-%b-%Y`, in the dates columns is based on functions from the `lubridate`package:

```
library(lubridate)
dataset[apply(dataset, 2, function(x) all(grepl(date_patterns, x)))] <-
  apply(dataset[apply(dataset, 2, function(x) all(grepl(date_patterns, x)))], 2, 
             function(x) format(parse_date_time(x, orders = date_formats), "%d-%b-%Y"))
```

This is the result:

```
dataset
  Customer_Name Country Transaction    Delivery      Return Cost
1             A       X 01-Mär-2015 01-Feb-2018 27-Nov-2009 1234
2             B       Y 31-Jan-2012 01-Aug-2016 22-Jan-2013 5678
3             C       Z 15-Jan-1999 17-Sep-2007 20-Nov-1987 6655
```

**EDIT 2**:

Here's another solution, using the package `anytime`:

```
library(anytime)
dataset[apply(dataset, 2, function(x) all(grepl(date_patterns, x)))] <- 
  apply(dataset[apply(dataset, 2, function(x) all(grepl(date_patterns, x)))], 2,   
        function(x) format(anydate(x), "%d-%b-%Y"))
```

Comment: The function first needs to identify which columns have DATE data.

Comment: See edit: the code now first checks whether columns match date patterns.

Comment: the input date is '01-11-2019'. The result date that I want should be '01-Nov-2019'

Comment: Have changed the code accordingly. Hope that's what you need!

Comment: It's been quite some work. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I am having more than one format in single column for a date. I want to replace all those format to a single format i.e %d-%b-%y. For example Transaction  = c("01-02-2009","01/04/2009","15-July-2019"). I want to replace all to %d-%b-%y.

Comment: Have adapted the code to accommodate for different formats of dates.

Comment: Can we also add H M S(hours, minutes and seconds) as more date formats?

Comment: Yes, just adapt the vector `date_formats <- c("%d-%m-%Y", "%d/%m/%Y", "%d-%b-%Y")`accordingly.